# Find the equation of an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

I have to find the equation of an ellipse which passes through the point $(3, 2)$, has center at the origin and major axis along the y-axis, i.e., is a vertical ellipse. No other info is given. I've tried a lot but it seems too hard to figure out.

Comment: So, do you know the general form of the equation of an ellipse with center at the origin and axes along the coordinate axes?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Yes.

Comment: Good: what is it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: $\frac{(x^2)}{(a^2)}+\frac{(y^2)}{(b^2)}=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your point $(3,2)$ into $\frac {x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and solve for $b$ to get
$$
b=-\frac {2a}{\sqrt{a^2-9}}.
$$
Set $a\gt 3$ and you get the family of ellipses that pass through $(3,2)$ and have center at the origin, since 
$$
\frac{3^2}{a^2}+\frac{2^2}{\left(-\frac {2a}{\sqrt{a^2-9}}\right)^2}=1
$$
is true for any $a$.

Comment: If $a\le3$, then $\sqrt{a^2-9}$ isn't real.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes sorry, I edited...

Comment: If $a\ge b$, the major axis won't be along the $y$-axis, so there's a constraint on $a$.